# how can I generate 6 month dates from a specific date

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table pqdf.
which have `Effective_Date` column, first I will do distinct of `Effective_Date`.
now from this date I want to generate 6 months dates,
if my start date is `2022-01-01` then my table last row value will be `2022-06-30`. and total row count be around 181 rows

```
+----------------+
| Effective_Date | 
+----------------+
| 2022-01-01     |
| 2022-01-01     |
| 2022-01-01     |
+----------------+
```

please help

I tried below but query but its not working.

```
select explode (sequence( first_value(to_date('Effective_Date'))), to_date(DATEADD(month, 6, Effective_Date)), interval 1 day) as date from pqdf
```

Comment: What does `Start_date` do with `Effective_Date`?

Comment: both are same, just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works. If it doesn't, can you please also provide the error message that you are seeing?

```
WITH pqdf AS (
    SELECT "2022-01-01" AS Effective_Date
)
SELECT
  EXPLODE(SEQUENCE(
      DATE(Effective_Date),
      TO_DATE(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, DATE(Effective_Date))),
      INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ) AS date
FROM
  pqdf
```

Comment: yes, its working fine. Thank you vinoaj

Comment: could you please look this question once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018294/lead-function-with-date-scenario

Comment: Great @AkashKhare. If it works, please feel free to mark the answer as accepted. I'll take a look at your other question shortly

Comment: could you please look my above issue once